# How to GPG sign only a particular unsigned commit?

Tags: git, gpg-signature

I have an issue where I committed something earlier without GPG signing it while for the rest of the commits, I installed gpg and signed them. I want to gpg sign this one particular commits. Is there an apt way to gpg sign a particular commit using the commit hash?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the signature is stored inside the commit, so the only way to sign an existing commit would be to re-create it and all its descendants, e.g. with an interactive rebase.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37742030/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+sign+existing+commit

Answer (score 1):

A commit is signed at the time the commit is created -- the signature is part of the commit.

Depending on your situation you have three options:

- Create a signed followup-commit. Note that you can create empty commits with `--allow-empty`.
- Amend the last commit and sign it. This is "history rewriting" (search term) and should be done if you understand the consequences for your peers.
- Create a signed tag pointing to you commit and communicate the tag.